# Different solution in Matematica and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, wolfram-mathematica, solver, equation-solving

This is another "my-results-doesn't-match-wolfram-website question".

I recently decided to give a try to python (I'm not sure why, to be honest, I'm spending too much time of my research in learn something which I don't know if I will use... Curiosity I suppose). I'm a really novel beginner in Python, so for start, I try to solve this equation:

```
cos(x)*cosh(x)=1
```

Using python, I wrote the next code:

```
from scipy import optimize 
import numpy as np

func = lambda x : np.cos(x*1.0)*np.cosh(x*1.0)-1.0

for iii in range(1,10):
    solution = fsolve(func, iii*1.0)
    print(solution)
```

For my surprise, I discover the solution is different from [wolfram website](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos(x)*cosh(x)%3D1)

Basically, my solution has some "residual solutions" I would say, probably because of numerical errors.

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or forgetting something, but the code looks (in my opinion) good.

Any ideas to fix the code will be appreciated.

Thanks very much to all. Kind regards,

German

============= UPDATE ==========

Interestingly, Matlab gets the correct results.

```
NM=5                            ; 
Beta_InitialModal=0             ;
Beta_FinalModal=8*NM            ;

F = @(Beta1) (-1+cos(Beta1)*cosh(Beta1)) ; %Equation of cantilever beam
interval = [Beta_InitialModal, Beta_FinalModal];
N =(Beta_FinalModal-Beta_InitialModal)*50 ;
start_pts = linspace(interval(1),interval(2),N);
found_roots = [];

for iii=1:numel(start_pts)-1
    if length(found_roots)==NM
        break
    else         
        try %#ok<TRYNC>
            found_roots(end+1) = fzero(F,[start_pts(iii),start_pts(iii+1)]); %#ok<SAGROW>
        end
    end 
end
display(found_roots);
```

Is it Python worse than Matlab/Mathematica? I don't think so...

I think maybe it's the input format number? Like `fsolve` works with a lower precision number than Matlab ? I don't know honestly.

Kind regards,

Comment: I would like to comment the python solution to add more information to the reader:
[ 0.00016521]
[ 0.00013716]
[ 0.00015346]
[ 4.73004074]
[ 4.73004074]
[ 4.73004074]
[-0.00011505]
[ 7.85320462]
[ 7.85320462]

Thanks very much to all. Kind regards,

Comment: The results look fairly consistent to me... If you plug the values back into `func`, they are all within 2.44960718e-10 of 0 (which is less than the default tolerance of `fsolve`).

Comment: @mgilson Thanks very much for your reply. Shall I assume that Wolfram is more accurate than python? I suppose it is related with the method used. Kind regards.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure that I'd make any real assumptions.  Different methods will have better/worse performance depending on the problem.  As with all numeric results, you need to be careful how you interpret the results and always check to see if they make sense...

Comment: You've already answered your question: *'Basically my solution has some "residual solutions" I would say, probably because of numerical errors.'*

Comment: @mgilson My "problem" is ... if I cannot rely on the python for that simple equation. Maybe I'm wasting the time. I mean I cannot check all solutions always, better go back to matlab (?)

Comment: @warrenWeckesser Thanks very much for your answer. It's good to know maybe I'm not too wrong. I would like to think there have to be a way to setup Python to give the same answer as in Mathematica... better a way to Python behaves like Mathematica?? Numerically speaking. Kind regards.

Comment: Because of floating point limitations, `func(x)` returns 0 for *any* x in the interval [-1.5e-4, 1.5e-4].  And it returns numbers that `fsolve` will consider to be approximately 0 in a slightly bigger interval.

Comment: Your matlab version only finds the exact zero because you give  an exact zero as one initial guess.  Set `Beta_InitialModal` to anything else and you won't get the zero.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you realize, but your equation has infinitely many solutions, which, except for zero, are very close to the zeros of `Cos` or approximately `(n+1/2) Pi` for large `n`.

The wolfram alpha page is a bit misleading in not telling you that.

Here are the first 100 solutions:  ( plus `0` ) using mathematica with extended precision:

```
x /. FindRoot[ Cos[x] Cosh[x] == 1 , {x, (# + 1/2) Pi }, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 1000] & /@ Range[101]
```

> 4.7300407448627040260, 7.8532046240958375565, 10.995607838001670907, 14.137165491257464177, 17.278759657399481438, 20.420352245626061091, 23.561944902040455075, 26.703537555508186248, 29.845130209103254267, 32.986722862692819562, 36.128315516282622650, 39.269908169872415463, 42.411500823462208720, 45.553093477052001958, 48.694686130641795196, 51.836278784231588435, 54.977871437821381673, 58.119464091411174912, 61.261056745000968150, 64.402649398590761388, 67.544242052180554627, 70.685834705770347865, 73.827427359360141104, 76.969020012949934342, 80.110612666539727581, 83.252205320129520819, 86.393797973719314058, 89.535390627309107296, 92.676983280898900535, 95.818575934488693773, 98.960168588078487012, 102.10176124166828025, 105.24335389525807349, 108.38494654884786673, 111.52653920243765997, 114.66813185602745320, 117.80972450961724644, 120.95131716320703968, 124.09290981679683292, 127.23450247038662616, 130.37609512397641940, 133.51768777756621263, 136.65928043115600587, 139.80087308474579911, 142.94246573833559235, 146.08405839192538559, 149.22565104551517883, 152.36724369910497207, 155.50883635269476530, 158.65042900628455854, 161.79202165987435178, 164.93361431346414502, 168.07520696705393826, 171.21679962064373150, 174.35839227423352473, 177.49998492782331797, 180.64157758141311121, 183.78317023500290445, 186.92476288859269769, 190.06635554218249093, 193.20794819577228417, 196.34954084936207740, 199.49113350295187064, 202.63272615654166388, 205.77431881013145712, 208.91591146372125036, 212.05750411731104360, 215.19909677090083683, 218.34068942449063007, 221.48228207808042331, 224.62387473167021655, 227.76546738526000979, 230.90706003884980303, 234.04865269243959627, 237.19024534602938950, 240.33183799961918274, 243.47343065320897598, 246.61502330679876922, 249.75661596038856246, 252.89820861397835570, 256.03980126756814893, 259.18139392115794217, 262.32298657474773541, 265.46457922833752865, 268.60617188192732189, 271.74776453551711513, 274.88935718910690837, 278.03094984269670160, 281.17254249628649484, 284.31413514987628808, 287.45572780346608132, 290.59732045705587456, 293.73891311064566780, 296.88050576423546103, 300.02209841782525427, 303.16369107141504751, 306.30528372500484075, 309.44687637859463399, 312.58846903218442723, 315.73006168577422047, 318.87165433936401370

Those larger values require extended precision to find..

```
 Plot[ Cos[x] Cosh[x] - 1 , {x , 310, 320 }]
```

[image]

Note even at high precision mathematica's `FindRoot` won't return an exact zero if we give an initial guess close to zero

```
FindRoot[Cos[x] Cosh[x] == 1, {x, 1/100}]  (* x -> 0.000148132 *)
FindRoot[Cos[x] Cosh[x] == 1, {x, 1/100}, WorkingPrecision -> 100] (* x -> ~3 10^-15 *)
```

of course if the initial guess is zero `FindRoot` returns 0..

```
FindRoot[Cos[x] Cosh[x] == 1, {x, 0}] (* x->0. *)
```

Comment: thanks very much for your reply. I really knew there are infinite solutions. I just wanted to get unless 5 (in the original code I have a condition which stop the algorithm when it reachs 5 solutions).

I suppose the code you attached is mathematica. Am I right?

Kind regards.

Comment: yes, that's mathematica.  You will likely only accurately get the roots up to `+/- ~26` using machine precision computation.

Comment: But if it's a machine precision problem, shouldn't I get the same results? Matlab gets the correct answer: